# Get data from matSnackBar with openFromComponent

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hey I'm new on Angular and I want get data from matsnackbar.

Is it possible ?

```
    apiName: string;

    this.snackBar.openFromComponent(CustomSnackbarComponent, {
        duration: 5000000,
        data: this.apiName;
    });
```

My component :

```
export class CustomSnackBarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  } 

}
```

Comment: A snackbar should not hold any logic. What do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to inject `MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA` in your snackbar component:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA} from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'your-snack-bar',
  template: '{{ data }}',
})
export class CustomSnackBarComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) { }
}
```

Comment: Here a link to the documention: https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview#sharing-data-with-a-custom-snack-bar